# MPDF 57, not working in Windows

Tags: php, html, image, pdf, mpdf

I have used a particular code to download pdf using "MPDF 57":

```
         ob_start(); 
         ob_clean(); // cleaning the buffer before Output()
         $html = '
         <div style="font-weight:bold;font-size:40px;color:#264664";>Title</div>
         <img  src='.$imgsrc.' name="image1">

            ';

        $mpdf=new mPDF('c','A4');
        $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
        $mpdf->Output('Chart_'.time().'.pdf','D');
        exit;
```

I got this code working fine for UBUNTU. But it failed in Windows. When the downloaded file is opened with any reader, it throws error message that file is corrupted. What has gone wrong with the code? I cannot find why this piece of code works only for browsers in Ubuntu OS and not for browsers in windows OS?

Comment: Do you mean it failed in a browser on Windows, or it failed on a WAMP stack? Or...?

Comment: @larsAnders It failed for all browsers in Windows OS. It works only in Ubuntu OS

Comment: Here are a couple more things to try - 1) Check that Adobe Reader is updated on the Windows machine.  2) mPDF works with UTF-8 encoded output. There is [a method in mPDF](http://mpdf1.com/manual/index.php?tid=220) to convert special html characters (which ould be in the img source string) $html = strcode2utf($html); before the WriteHTML line. 3) You might try changing 'D' to 'I' in your Output call, just to see if the browsers are able to display the PDF inline.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that it's a parse error that Ubuntu can handle but Windows cannot. You have two tiny syntax errors. First, a semicolon out of place:

```
<div style="font-weight:bold;font-size:40px;color:#264664";>Title</div>
```

Should be:

```
<div style="font-weight:bold;font-size:40px;color:#264664;">Title</div>
                                                ---------^
```

And second, missing quotes around the src attribute:

```
<img  src='.$imgsrc.' name="image1" />
```

Should be:

```
<img src="'.$imgsrc.'" name="image1">
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But it didn't work out even after changes